# Google Workspace Marketplace Listing

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

i have recently added a product to the task management section of the Google Workspace Marketplace which has been approved and if I search for it I can find it. But if I click on the task Management category I do not see it in that list. Is that list limited, if yes, how do you get to appear in that list?

Many Thanks
Colm

Added saas product to task management category but am not able to see it in that category.

Answer (score 0):

The list of apps in the category is limited to 100 at this time. Your app will need to increase the install count to rank higher.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).